# Rails Testing Default Value in database fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, null, minitest, byebug

Ok, so I am running a Postgres database in Rails 4 and for one of my models Offer the attribute `:offer_status` should default to declined. Here is my migration:

```
def change
    create_table :offers do |t|
      t.integer :offer_status, default: 0

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
```

This `:offer_status` attribute refers to an enum in the model like so:

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
 enum offer_status: [:declined, :accepted]
end
```

With these two in place I have written a test that will check if a newly created offer will have a default `offer_status` of 0.

```
 test "new offers should default to declined" do
    @offer2=Offer.new()
    assert @offer2.declined?
  end
```

When I call the byebug console mid-test and puts @offer2 I get this:

```
(byebug) o
<Offer id: nil,  offer_status: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
(byebug) exit
```

However, if I do the exact same call `o=Offer.new()` in the rails console it returns:

```
 2.2.0 :001 > o=Offer.new
 => #<Offer id: nil, offer_status: 0, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

So my question is, why does it work in the console but fail in my tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why it does behave differently in the tests, but what you should be aware of, is that the `default: 0` is a instruction for your **database**. It becomes part of the table definition.

Calling `new` will create a new ruby object instance, which will have not touched the database until you try to save it. Defining a default just tells the database 'if you don't receive a value for this column, put 0 in it` - But until you send your new Object with save via a SQL query to the DB, this will have absolutely no effect on your object.

Comment: I added a @offer2.save!  in between the two lines of my test and it still saves as nil. Any idea why?

Comment: No sorry, add a validation `validates :offer_status, presence: true` to your model class and a NOT-NULL constraint `t.integer :offer_status, default: 0, null: false ` - this way NIL can not be stored in the db, and you will get pointed to the place where it actually fails

Comment: Even with the validation and the db constraint everything still comes up as nil, I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem. I had to change an already executed migration (to add a default to 0 and to specify `null: false`). I executed `rake db:rollback STEP=1` and then I've rerun the migration. Everything worked fine, in rails console I was able to see that for every object created the default value for that attribute was 0, but in tests it was always `nil`. What it solved it for me was to drop the database (no important data there), recreate it, run the migrations and the tests were executed without failures or errors.

I should mention maybe, that even before I've dropped the database, in the `schema.db` for that column the default was already 0 and `null: false`. Maybe `rake test` uses a different schema, something cached, and not the newest one...